# what is the following error in H2 database? And how to resolve the error?

Tags: h2

When I am creating a table in H2 database, as following:

```
CREATE TABLE data2 (end_lat DOUBLE, end_lng DOUBLE, member_casual CHAR(7) unique, 
                    month INTEGER, week INTEGER, day INTEGER, Year INTEGER,
                    day_of_week CHAR(10), tod TIME, ride_length INTEGER);
```

Then I am getting the error as below,

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE data2 (end_lat DOUBLE, end_lng DOUBLE, member_casual CHAR(7) unique, \000d\000a\0009\0009\0009\0009\0009[*]month INTEGER, week INTEGER, day INTEGER, Year INTEGER,\000d\000a\0009\0009\0009\0009\0009day_of_week CHAR(10), tod TIME, ride_length INTEGER)"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE data2 (end_lat DOUBLE, end_lng DOUBLE, member_casual CHAR(7) unique,
                    month INTEGER, week INTEGER, day INTEGER, Year INTEGER,
                    day_of_week CHAR(10), tod TIME, ride_length INTEGER) [42001-214] 42001/42001 (Help)
```

When I tried to create a table as following,

```
CREATE TABLE data2 (end_lat DOUBLE, end_lng DOUBLE, member_casual CHAR(7) unique, 
                    month INTEGER, week INTEGER, day INTEGER, Year INTEGER,
                    day_of_week CHAR(10), tod TIME, ride_length INTEGER);
```

I was expecting it to create a table as it worked for me when I tried it in MySQL.

Appreciate it, if anyone can help me resolve this.

Comment: Remove excess CR/LF/TAB characters before `day_of_week` column definition.

Answer (score 1):

**Answering to my own question**

After changing the names of the column definition's to the following:

CREATE TABLE data2 (end_lat DOUBLE, end_lng DOUBLE, member_casual CHAR(7) not null unique, month_is INTEGER, week_is INT, day_is INTEGER, year_is INTEGER, day_of_week CHAR(10), tod TIME, ride_length INTEGER);

It Helped me resolve the error.

Comment: Yes. Or `CREATE TABLE data2 (
 end_lat DOUBLE PRECISION,
 end_lng DOUBLE PRECISION,
 member_casual CHAR(7),
 "month" INTEGER,
 week INTEGER,
 "day" INTEGER,
 "year" INTEGER,
     day_of_week CHAR(10),
     tod TIME,
     ride_length INTEGER);`

Comment: So what was the error?